# Unit test / mock getAttribute angular5

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm unit testing a method that begins with an if statement like

```
if(document.body.querySelector('#elementID li').getAttribute('disabled') === 'false')
```

My HTML code looks like:

```
<ul id="elementID">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; [attr.disabled]="data.isDisabled""></li>
</ul>
```

No matter what I do, I always get the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null**. I know how to test the logic after the if statement, I just cannot get past it.

I've tried to create the li dynamically in my tests and I used the setAttribute like

```
 it('should test', () => {
    let element = document.createElement('ul')
    element.setAttribute('id', 'elementID')
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.setAttribute('disabled', 'false');
    element.appendChild(li);
    component.Method();
    expect(someVariable).toBeTruthy();
 }
```

but that doesn't work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please include code of your test, also would be great if you provided demo reproducing your scenario.

Comment: You're making your life hard by not using Angular as it's supposed to be used. Don't do DOM manipulation in your code. The code should use its model, and the DOM should be generated by the template, based on this model. So your code should use `if (!this.data.isDisabled)`  instead of what it does now.

Comment: I agree with no DOM manipulation, but this is a project I inherited and I wasn't trying to make too many changes to the source.

Comment: that's fair...I see that you are saying JB Nizet